# Difference between "understand" and "comprehend"

Tags: differences

Is there a difference in the meaning or the usage of the verbs *understand* and *comprehend*? Which one would fit best in the following sentence?

> In order to speak and **understand/comprehend** a language, there has
>   to be a representation of the words.

Comment: This may be answered by a comparison of the two words in a good dictionary. Voting to close as general reference.

Comment: @Robusto: a dictionary won't tell you relative rarity or register.

Comment: Why are many interesting questions closed? This question at least addresses 1) Usage, word choice, and grammar and 2) Etymology (history of words’ development), beyond anything a dictionary can provide. I like questions to improve my comprehension and understanding of English, not just correct grammar mistakes or wrong term usage.

Comment: @Vladtn: Well, ask yourself this: "Why did I choose *comprehension* instead of *understanding* in my third sentence?"

Comment: @Robusto "The English Language and Usage Stack Exchange is for linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts. Questions on the following topics are welcomed here:
- Word choice and usage"

Answer (score 1):

*Comprehend* (through its Latin etymology, from *comprehendere*, *cum*: with + *prehendere*: grab) also has a spatial connotation, like *encompass*, by which one's thought *surrounds* a particular topic, like the hand an object, seeing all aspects and limits of a concept, but indeed, without maybe peeking inside like with true *understanding*.

Answer (score 1):

They are mostly synonymous but 'understand' is much more everyday than 'comprehend'.

Also, in addition to the connotation of 'inclusion', 'comprehend' is more intense.

Answer (score 0):

The words are synonymous but have slight difference between them.  Understanding has a connotation of a deeper, fuller realization of a matter while comprehension is less deep and less full.

For an example, assume a person spoke elemental Spanish.  If this person read a bit of poetry, he might comprehend the words but could easily not understand the meaning.

Comment: Hm ... Interesting, in OALD it is explained the other way round, [unstanding](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/understand): to know or realize the meaning of words or to know or realize how or why something happens, but [comprehend](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/comprehend): to understand something **fully**, while comprehend is often used in negative sentences.

Comment: There will be localized differences, for instance in Canada there are a lot of "reading comprehension" tests, I think this testing also extends into the United States and so "comprehension" can mean that you understand what is being said but only at a superficial level. Because of how common these tests are and how early they are administered and how seldom the use of the word "comprehension" is used, this connotation is dominant. Understanding is considered something deeper, perhaps having the ability to actually perform described tasks for instance.