# understand and comprehend usage

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

This post is make of a few related questions.

Q1. Which structure is more preferred?

```
This method is hard to understand for students.
This method is hard to be understood by students.
```

Q2. Which structure is more preferred?

```
This method is hard to comprehend for students.
This method is hard to be comprehend by students.
```

Q3. In very formal writing is comprehend preferred over understand?

Q4. Is comprehend = understand always (as far as it is related to understanding a method)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use:

> This method is challenging/difficult for students to understand/comprehend

Did you see the following question already answered which might aid with your understanding? :-)

[Difference between "understand" and "comprehend"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62315/difference-between-understand-and-comprehend)

Comment: Will it also aid with his comprehension? :)

Answer (score 2):

None of them. I would use:

> This method is hard for students to understand/comprehend.

or

> This method is not easily understood by students.

I wouldn't use *comprehend* in this second version. Since it uses the past tense, it would have to be *comprehended*, and I find that a cumbersome word for some reason.

Comment: I would tend to agree that your examples flow better. But, though cumbersome, there is nothing grammatically incorrect with either of the OP's. *Understand* and *comprehend* are very close synonyms, and one has little rank over the other. It is a classic instance of there being two words, one of Old English/Germanic origin - *understonden*  and another meaning almost the same thing of Norman French origin - *comprendre*

Comment: The question was which is more preferred. So while the sentences in the question may be grammatical, I don't think they're the preferred way to write it. As for _comprehend_ versus _understand_, OSFox linked to another question that addresses that more completely.